# Interpolation weights in matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation

How can I find the interpolation weights used by functions such as griddedInterpolant in matlab. Instead of wanting the interpolated value, I want to know which points were used with which weightings to calculate that value. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: From the [`griddedInterpolant` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolantclass.html) it does not appear that there is a particular set of weights - rather different approaches on how to interpolate the data (specified by `method`).

Comment: So there is no way of retrieving the weights it uses to interpolate a new value?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *weights*? For example, if you use the `nearest` method, your data point will be assigned the value of the nearest neighbor (hence the name). So, technically, there is no weight. Unless you wanted to say that the nearest neighbor has a weight of `1` and all other points of `0`.

Comment: Let's [take a step back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): Why do you want to obtain the weights?

Comment: By weights I mean what you describe. The weights that would be used to interpolate the value, so for nearest neighbour: 1 for the nearest point and 0 for all others. I have written a function to calculate the weights with linear interpolation, but it would just make more sense to use those weights which the function which interpolates the values (e.g. griddedInterpolant) uses, also meaning less work for me since at some stage they are calculated by the function anyway.